# css margin troubles in IE

Tags: css

I'm having trouble with margins in IE. The left nav, the center, and the right nav are all going to the left instead of being centered. There is no problem in other browsers.

```
#container{
    margin:0px auto;
    width:1000px;
    height:90%;
}

#center{
    border-left:1px solid #3D3D3D;
    border-right:1px solid #3D3D3D;
    float:left;
    width:46%;
    height:100%;
}

#left_nav{
    border-bottom:1px solid #3d3d3d;
    border-left:1px solid #3d3d3d;
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    height:auto;
    padding:2;
}

#right_nav{
    border-bottom:1px solid #3D3d3d;
    border-right:1px solid #3d3d3d;
    float:left;
    width:27%;
    height:auto;
    padding:4;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:8px;
}
```

Comment: That's because you have `float: left` on each element... what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: For `#right_nav` you have `padding:4;` no size specified px etc. You also are missing the px size in your left nav padding.

Comment: I dont see you use any margin in the css

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the #container div. The other divs are inside it.

Comment: What exactly is happening? Could you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? I don't understand what you mean about centering them.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/igitar/edit#preview It's fine here. It's just IE that's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a doctype as the very first line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Without this, IE is in quirks mode which emulates IE 5.5.

You'll also need to add something similar to `html, body { height: 100%; }`.